# SSO - Platform-licensed vs community users

Tags: single-sign-on

Salesforce is using SSO with PING as Identity management where salesforce is SP and PING is Idp. There is a scenario where one user has salesforce platform license and same user is also a customer portal user with portal license.

Is there any way that salesforce can check additional attributes (user license) along with federation ID after PING send those attributes in SAML response?

Comment: Out of the box - no.

Comment: What other option I can look for?

Comment: Have all users go to the community, then use [startURL](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sso_provider_addl_params_start.htm&type=5) to redirect them wherever they need to go.